# How to solve cudaSetDevice Error and run this deep-learning code correctly?

Tags: matlab, cuda, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I use the following GPU code on the facial expression recognition:
http://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-faces/

My system is the same as the authors' but the CUDA version is a little higher (5.5) than the authors' (5.0).

When I run the "script_face_exp.m", it said that "Error using mexcuConvNNoo Assertion Failed: cudaSetDevice Error!'.
It's caused by:
cudaErrorInvalidDevice  This indicates that the device ordinal supplied by the user does not correspond to a valid CUDA device.

But I can use GPU for computations and the codes based on theano worked on GPU well.

How can I solve use GPU to run the code correctly?

Comment: whoch GPU have you installed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`script_face_exp` calls function `gg` which sets these global variables:

```
function [] = gg( gpunumber )
global GPUID;
global FERMI;
GPUID = 3;
FERMI = 1;
```

The global variable `GPUID` is later used in `SelectGPUFromServer` to set the used GPU.

You probably do not have a GPU with ID 3 (which means having at least 4 GPUs installed), so you should change `gg` to set this variable to e.g. `0` (if you have one GPU).